# Setting local notification using iOS7 app background refresh

Tags: ios, ios7, localnotification

As you all know we have limitations for setting local notifications in iOS, about 64.

Now, is it possible to set notifications in background using the new iOS7 app background refresh state?

I mean, imagine the app is closed, so is it possible to set a new local notification when a notification just fired for user?

I just want to always have all my 64 notifications in notification center without forcing the user to open the app again. I need always have notifications even if user didn't open the app for a year.

Appreciate any help,
Elias

Comment: any solution found .

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if this violates some intended usage by Apple, and this example hasn't been tested in a production app that has gotten through the approval process, but you can try the new background fetch API. In the target capabilities, enable "Background Fetch".

Be sure and add this to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in your app delegate:

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
```

Then add this delegate method:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    ...Schedule your local notifications here...
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

You need to call the completion handler, although it's unclear which status you should return since you are not actually fetching data.